# Changing img src using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

**Disclaimer: I'm writing a theme file for a web app that doesn't allow me to manipulate the core files of the app, so I cannot change the order in which files load in the DOM.

I have a JS file that allows me to add custom scripts to the page.  I am coding in jQuery.

I want to change the image source of one of the elements on the page. The image's source is loaded to the page dynamically by a core JS file that I cannot touch, that is loaded after my file...

Let's say the HTML is:

```
<div class ="parent">
    <img src="http://example.com/image.jpg">
</div>
```

When I add something like the following to my jQuery doc:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function fixImgSrc(){
        var newSrc = 'http://example.com/new-image.jpg';
        var image = $('.parent').find('img');
        if (image.attr('src') !== newSrc){
            image.attr('src', newSrc);
        }
    };
    fixImgSrc;
});
```

When I run this function, it returns `undefined` since images are loaded after the jQuery.  I need to do this multiple times throughout the code to correct images.  Sometimes I can get around this by running the function as:

```
 setTimeout(fixImgSrc(), 500);
```

which runs the function after everything else has loaded.  Other times the only way I can get this to work throughout the site is by doing the miserable:

```
 setInterval(fixImgSrc(), 500);
```

to keep checking if the new source has been taken.

Is there a better less tacky way to do this?  This seems like it's a hack and not the "right" way to do it.  Plus the load on the browser is intense running the same command over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
FixImgSrc();
}
```

Here it will let the function work after the ready state of the document

Try this

```
    var image = $('.parent').find('img');
image.on("load",function(){
    if (image.attr('src') !== newSrc){
        image.attr('src', newSrc);
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that, being jQuery, everything is already wrapped in a $(document).ready() statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   alert("ready ");
   FixImgSrc();
  }
```

I think first you need to check is your jquery is working or not.

Comment: Everything is already working and it's already wrapped in a document.ready wrapper